# Div not touching the top of the browser even with CSS Reset

Tags: html, css

I'm making a project and I need to create a div that goes up where the user will can change his picture, so, I did this:

```
<div class="mudar_foto_form" style="z-index: 5; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
</div>
```

But, the div does not reach the top of the page:
http://prntscr.com/eys8lp

I even tried to use:

```
html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px;
    }
```

And even so a css reset:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

But still not touching the top of the page, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you upload your code at JSFiddle or similar? Setting `top: 0; left: 0;width:100%;height:100%` should definitely solve your issue, but it would be good to see your current code working so far.

Comment: umm... `top:0;`?

Comment: Try adding `left:0;top:0` - you haven't given your element a position so the browser kind of has to guess what you mean.

Comment: Yes, no top property set

Comment: @wlin thanks, I havent noticed that

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol thanks too

Answer (score 0):

So, I forgot to do top: 0, thanks to Niet the Dark Absol and wlin